# Comparing data from 2 nested dictionaries and producing a box-plot

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, nested, boxplot

I am trying to produce a box plot using matplotlib with data from nested dictionaries. Below is a rough outline of the structure of dictionary in question.

```
m_data = {scenario:{variable:{'model_name':value, ''model_name':value ...}
```

One issue is that I want to look at the change in the models output between the two different scenarios ( scenario 1 [VAR1] - scenario 2 [VAR2]) and then plot this difference in a box plot.

I have managed to do this, however, I want to be able to label the outliers with the model name. My current method separates the keys from the values, therefore the outlier data point has no name associated with it anymore.

```
    #BOXPLOT
#set up blank lists
future_rain = []
past_rain = []
future_temp = []
past_temp = []

#single out the values for each model from the nested dictioaries
for key,val in m_data[FUTURE_SCENARIO][VAR1].items():
    future_rain.append(val)
for key,val in m_data[FUTURE_SCENARIO][VAR2].items():
    future_temp.append(val)
for key,val in m_data['historical'][VAR1].items():
   past_rain.append(val)
for key,val in m_data['historical'][VAR2].items():
    past_temp.append(val)

#blanks for final data
bx_plt_rain = []
bx_plt_temp = []

#allow for the subtration of two lists
zip_object = zip(future_temp, past_temp)
for future_temp_i, past_temp_i in zip_object:
    bx_plt_temp.append(future_temp_i - past_temp_i)

zip_object = zip(future_rain, past_rain)
for future_rain_i, past_rain_i in zip_object:
    bx_plt_rain.append(future_rain_i - past_rain_i)

#colour ouliers red

c = 'red'

outlier_col = {'flierprops': dict(color =c, markeredgecolor=c)}

#plot

bp = plt.boxplot(bx_plt_rain, patch_artist=True, showmeans=True, vert= False, meanline=True, **outlier_col)
bp['boxes'][0].set(facecolor = 'lightgrey')
plt.show()
```

If anyone knows of a workaround for this I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

As a bit of a hack you could create a function that looks through the dict for the outlier value and returns the key.

```
def outlier_name(outlier_val, inner_dict):
    for key, value in inner_dict.items():
        if value == outlier_val:
            return key
```

This could be pretty intensive if your data sets are large.